# Добавить класс каждой сылке в теге li первой линии вложенности

Tags: jquery

Нужно добавить класс с помощью jQuery каждой ссылке "Название раздела" первой линии вложенности вне зависимости от уровней вложенности дерева. Простым языком - нужно выделить только название каждого раздела. Псевдоклассы `:first` и `:first-child` не помогают, так как добавляют класс или только первому элементу, или всем ссылкам дерева.
[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/he7q3hk5/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fyta3p4d/

Comment: >  прямые потомки

Comment: soledar10, спасибо большое! А я голову сломал. Так просто...

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос, только там не класс надо было добавить, а отобразить ([ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511001/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/511049#511049)).

Решение перебором:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parent = $('ul:first'),
        highlight = $('li a', parent); // ссылки со всех линий вложенности
  highlight = highlight.filter(function(){
    return !$('ul', parent).has($(this)).length; // проверка вложенности
  });
  highlight.addClass('link');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/he7q3hk5/