# Релизация древовидной раскрывающейся вложенности

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть дерево:

```
<div class="sh-parent">
  <a href="#" class="sh-btn">1</a>
  <ul class="sh-content">
    <li>1.1</li>
    <li class="sh-parent">
      <a href="#" class="sh-btn">1.2</a>
      <ul class="sh-content">
        <li>1.2.1</li>
        <li>1.2.2</li>
        <li>1.2.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Изначально все .sh-content скрыты. Дерево свернуто.
Необходимо чтобы дерево раскрывалось по одному уровню вложенности.
То есть нажали на 1 - открылось 1.1, 1.2. Нажали на 1.2 - открылось 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3

Есть такой код, но он раскрывает все вложенные .sh-content

```
var parent, content;

$(document).on('click', '.sh-parent .sh-btn', function(){
  parent = $('.sh-parent').has($(this)).last();
  content = $('.sh-content', parent);
  if (content.css('display') == 'none') {
    content.show();
  }
  else {
    content.hide();
  }
  return false;
});
```

Пробовал следующие варианты с определением `content` (не помогли):

```
content = $('> .sh-content, :not(.sh-parent) .sh-content', parent);
content = $('.sh-content', parent).not('.sh-parent .sh-content');
content = $('.sh-content', parent).not('.sh-content .sh-content');
```

Уточнение 1. Внутри .sh-parent может быть несколько .sh-content, которые надо раскрыть. Например:

```
<div class="sh-parent">
  <a href="#" class="sh-btn">1</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="sh-content">1.1</li>
    <li class="sh-content sh-parent">
      <a href="#" class="sh-btn">1.2</a>
      <ul class="sh-content">
        <li>1.2.1</li>
        <li>1.2.2</li>
        <li>1.2.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Уточнение 2. Могут быть совершенно разные вариации html. Надо быть не привязанным к ul и li. Необходимо оперировать только .sh-parent, .sh-content и .sh-btn.

Наработки можно посмотреть тут:
https://jsfiddle.net/q8c1rop1/, https://jsfiddle.net/q8c1rop1/1/

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233604/use-jquery-to-get-descendants-of-an-element-that-are-not-children-of-a-container) был. Не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить только перебором.

```
var parent, content, testParent;

$(document).on('click', '.sh-parent .sh-btn', function(){
  parent = $('.sh-parent').has($(this)).last();
  content = $('.sh-content', parent);
  content = content.filter(function(){
    return !$('.sh-parent', parent).has($(this)).length;
  });
  if (content.css('display') == 'none') {
    content.show();
  }
  else {
    content.hide();
  }
  return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q8c1rop1/3/

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, этот код разрешит Вашу проблему.

HTML:

```
<div class="sh-parent">
  <a href="#" class="sh-btn">1</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="sh-content">1.1</li>
    <li class="sh-content sh-parent">
      <a href="#" class="sh-btn">1.2</a>
      <ul class="sh-content">
        <li>1.2.1</li>
        <li>1.2.2</li>
        <li>1.2.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sh-content {

  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

    $('.sh-parent').click(function() {

        var elements = $(this).find('li.sh-content');

        if (elements.size() > 0) {

            elements.show('slow');
        }
        else {

            $(this).find('ul').show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Результат можно проверить тут:https://jsfiddle.net/1m30gt13/

Comment: Раньше так и было, но на деле имеется несколько .sh-content которые надо показать. Забыл об этом написать.

Comment: Вы можете выставить (или отредактировать вопрос) пример HTML кода, в котором есть то, что Вы не указали в примере?

Comment: Отредактировал, добавил.

Comment: В соответсвии с Вашей задачей, я отредактировал свой JavaScript код. Кажется, результат будет соотвествовать Вашим ожиданиям

Comment: Да. Но этот код решает конкретно эту задачу (с таким html). Но могут быть совершенно разные вариации. Надо быть не привязанным к ul и li. Только parent, content и btn

Comment: Добавлю этот комментарий в вопрос